# Lookaround alternative in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've tried to use lookahead/lookbehind in JavaScript (described at the [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) and figured out they're not supported.

What I'm trying to do actually, is to catch a `dar`, which isn't followed by `win`. So, a string `darblabla` should return `true`, while `darwinblabla` should be `false`.

Right now, my solution is: `/dar/i.test(string) && !/darwin/i.test(string)`.

This looks quite long, is there any shorter solution (regex string?), that can replace current statement?

Comment: The deal in SO is to vote up or down answers and accept the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
^dar(?!win)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/otv0h50fdkzbYs43)

**EDIT**

Regarding your second question

```
^(?!cyg)win
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bafYkU5rXhOytwAG)

Comment: @Shaels As explain in the Debuggex, you only need to check that your word begin by `dar` and is not followed by `win`. Debuggex is a great tool to develop regex BTW,

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to convert `/win/i.test(string) && !/cyg win/i.test(string)` in a same way?

Comment: @Shaels Yes, you need to invert the test. Check my update

Comment: Note that the `(?!cyg)` lookahead in `^(?!cyg)win` makes no sense since `(?!cyg)` checks if the first 3 characters are not `cyg`, and they are not since the first 3 characters must be `win`!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript should support negative lookahead.

```js
alert(/dar(?!win)/.test('darblahblah'))
alert(/dar(?!win)/.test('darwin'))
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /dar(?win)/: Invalid group

Comment: you forget to add `!`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use look-behinds in JavaScript, but you can use look-aheads.

So, this will yield `false`:

```js
document.write(/\bdar(?!win)/i.test("darwin"));
```

As for a look-behind, in most cases you can work around that limitation by using capturing groups, reversing strings and matches, or building your own parsers.

Here is a way to combine `/win/i.test(string) && !/cyg win/i.test(string)`:

```js
document.write(/niw(?!\s+gyc\b)/.test('cyg win'.split("").reverse().join("")));
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(/niw(?!\s+gyc\b)/.test('darwin'.split("").reverse().join("")));
```

Note the pattern - `niw(?!\s+gyc\b)` - must be reversed.